# Used git reset --hard. How to move HEAD back to the most recent commit?

Tags: git

I figured I could find the answer for this with a simple google search because it seems so simple and common, but every answer I'm finding is for a very specific situation that doesnt apply to me.

I had two local commits in my repository:
commitA - commitB(H)

(*the H means HEAD)

I wanted to view a snapshot of my code at commit A, so I did:
`git reset --hard A`
so now I have this
commitA(H) - commitB    (well, I'm HOPING B is still there)

I just want to go back to having B be my HEAD!

Comment: To view the snapshot of A you should have performed a checkout to A and not a hard reset

Comment: git reset --hard performs the following
Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded.

Comment: (insert gif of FML guy from superbad here)

Comment: No git saves you, you can use git reflog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Luck is with you, provided you have not disabled git's "reflogs": commit `B` *is* still there.  (Even if you have removed the airbags and seatbelts it's probably still there anyway. :-)  Reflog entries preserve commits for at least 30 days by default.)

If you know the SHA-1 ID of commit `B`:

```
$ git reset --hard <id of B>
```

will get it back.

If you *don't* know the ID of `B`, you must find it, or direct git to find it, but fortunately that's easy<sup>1</sup> since they are in the reflogs:

```
$ git reflog         # shows the reflog for HEAD
$ git reflog master  # shows the reflog for branch master
```

You can then copy-and-paste the ID, or use the `HEAD@{1}` style syntax that you'll see in the reflog output:

```
bf8be34 master@{0}: reset: moving to bf8be34bb970c875585952efc5c09898f98e1d10
d106870 master@{1}: commit: ...
```

Note that `--hard` will, as always, wreck any uncommitted work you have in the work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, "easy", if scanning through a bunch of SHA-1s and one-line commit messages to find the right one is "easy".  In an active repository, finding a buried reflog entry is tricky.  If you do a lot of rebasing and amending, the same commit message gets repeated a lot.  Fortunately in this case it's going to be `...@{1}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the commit hash of commit B you can

```
git checkout -b new_branch COMMIT_HASH
```

Then went back to the original branch and merge the new_branch:

```
git checkout branch
git merge new_branch
```

---

Btw, you should not use `reset --hard` if you want to view a previous commit. Use:

```
git checkout COMMIT_HASH
```

instead.

Comment: I do have the hash and that DID work, now was there a way to do this without creating a new branch?

Comment: @Siavash: yes, `git reset` "moves the branch": you give `git reset` a commit ID, and it changes the current branch to point to that commit ID.  If you don't give `git reset` a new commit ID, it still "moves" the branch, but it moves it from where it points now, to where it points now.  Think of the branch as a sticky-note, or as a name with an arrow on it.  You peel off the sticky-note, currently pasted on commit A, and paste it on B.  Or, you move the arrow so that it points to B instead of A.  Another `git reset` moves it again.

Comment: " was there a way to do this without creating a new branch" the same way as you messed it up: `git reset --hard HASH`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that `--hard` obliterated commitB entirely. As in [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553873/2736496), you can hopefully reflog the deleted commits, but I'm personally not familiar enough with reflog to comment on it.

You could have checked out A, which would have been a detached head (just a commit to which no branch is associated). At that point you could browse your code, and then either re-checked out B (`git checkout HEAD`), or continued with A in a new branch (`git checkout -b myNewBranch`).

For next time, here's a good post on the [differing versions of reset](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html).

Comment: There's also a good writeup of looking at, moving, and deleting commits in the accepted answer over at "Revert Git repo to a previous commit" http://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/1655180